# Plotting a normalized array in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to represent the array `Pe` using lines as shown in the current output but the colors of the lines do not reflect the actual array. For example, line marked `0` has the value `394.20560747663563` and should be blue instead it is yellow.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm
import math
from  numpy import nan

fig,aPe = plt.subplots(1)
n=3


N=2*n*(n-1)

J = np.array([[]])
Pe=np.array([[394.20560747663563, 408.7929050665396 , 419.132709901089  ,
       398.95097406721044, 403.81198021076113, 430.00914784982064,
       424.50127213826016, 453.54817733128607, 441.4651085668709 ,
       447.42507960635163, 413.8982415602072 , 390.3025816600353 ]])
             
             
             

C1 = nan

for i in J[0]:
    Pe = np.insert(Pe, i, [C1], axis=1)
print("Pe =", [Pe])



for i in range(0,len(Pe)):
    Max=max(max(Pe[i]), max(Pe[i]))
    Min=min(min(Pe[i]), min(Pe[i]))
a=Min
b=Max



Amax= math.ceil(Max)
Amin= math.floor(Min)
print(Amax, Amin)



color = cm.get_cmap('Dark2')
norm = Normalize(vmin=Amin, vmax=Amax)
color_list = []



for i in range(len(Pe[0])):
    color_list.append(color(Pe[0,i]/Amax))

id = 0
for j in range(0, n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        aPe.hlines(200+200*(n-j-1)+5*n, 200*(k+1)+5*n, 200*(k+2)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
        id += 1

    for i in range(0, n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i, 200+200*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        aPe.add_patch(rect)
        if j < n-1:
            aPe.vlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200*(n-1-j)+5*n, 200*(n-j)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
            id += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm))
cb.set_label("Entry pressure (N/m$^{2}$)")
aPe.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
aPe.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)


plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are trying to get your colors from `color()`. You need to first set the scale so that the value 390 `Amin` is equivalent to 0 and 454 `Amax` is equivalent to 1. To do this, subtract the `Amin` from the values then divide that by the difference of `Amax` and `Amin`. So the `color_list` will be created by:

```
for i in range(len(Pe[0])):
    color_list.append(color(((Pe[0,i])-Amin)/(Amax-Amin)))
```

The values are:

```
[394.20560747663563,
 408.7929050665396,
 419.132709901089,
 398.95097406721044,
 403.81198021076113,
 430.00914784982064,
 424.50127213826016,
 453.54817733128607,
 441.4651085668709,
 447.42507960635163,
 413.8982415602072,
 390.3025816600353]
```

And the values used for grabbing the colors from `color()` are:

```
[0.06571261682243179,
 0.2936391416646815,
 0.45519859220451586,
 0.1398589698001631,
 0.21581219079314273,
 0.6251429351534474,
 0.539082377160315,
 0.9929402708013448,
 0.8041423213573582,
 0.8972668688492442,
 0.3734100243782379,
 0.004727838438051357]
```

Which, when put all together, gives you the graph:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm
import math
from  numpy import nan

fig,aPe = plt.subplots(1)
n=3

N=2*n*(n-1)

J = np.array([[]])
Pe=np.array([[394.20560747663563, 408.7929050665396 , 419.132709901089  ,
       398.95097406721044, 403.81198021076113, 430.00914784982064,
       424.50127213826016, 453.54817733128607, 441.4651085668709 ,
       447.42507960635163, 413.8982415602072 , 390.3025816600353 ]])         
             
C1 = nan
for i in J[0]:
    Pe = np.insert(Pe, i, [C1], axis=1)
print("Pe =", [Pe])

for i in range(0,len(Pe)):
    Max=max(max(Pe[i]), max(Pe[i]))
    Min=min(min(Pe[i]), min(Pe[i]))
a=Min
b=Max
Amax= math.ceil(Max)
Amin= math.floor(Min)
print(Amax, Amin)

color = cm.get_cmap('Dark2')
norm = Normalize(vmin=Amin, vmax=Amax)
color_list = []
for i in range(len(Pe[0])):   
    color_list.append(color(((Pe[0,i])-Amin)/(Amax-Amin)))
    
id = 0
for j in range(0, n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        aPe.hlines(200+200*(n-j-1)+5*n, 200*(k+1)+5*n, 200*(k+2)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
        id += 1

    for i in range(0, n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i, 200+200*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        aPe.add_patch(rect)
        if j < n-1:
            aPe.vlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200*(n-1-j)+5*n, 200*(n-j)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
            id += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm), ticks=np.arange(Amin, Amax+len(color.colors), len(color.colors)))
cb.set_label("Entry pressure (N/m$^{2}$)")
aPe.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
aPe.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works but the colorbar is a bit odd. For example, ```400``` is somewhere in the orange band, ```410``` is at the center of purple band and so on. How can I fix so that the values are at the starting of each color band?

Comment: That has to do with your `fig.colorbar`'s tick scaling. You can set the ticks with `cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm), ticks=np.arange(Amin, Amax, len(color.colors)))`

Comment: I was wondering why  ```Amax=454``` is not written along the color bar but ```Amin=390``` is.

Comment: `cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm), ticks=np.arange(Amin, Amax+len(color.colors), len(color.colors)))`